# After changing the column width in a table in sql server, do I need to recreate the index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I've increased the width of a column from varchar(8) to varchar(10). Do I need to drop index of this column and recreate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to drop and recreate index - because it's meta data change only.
check below link for reference.

[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56917/when-changing-the-size-of-a-nvarchar-column-do-i-need-to-drop-the-unique-index)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure I get your question. In case you have a non-clustered index on that column => you cannot change datatype of the column before dropping the index.

Why? Because it has to allocate more space to the index.

An alternative would be:

1/ Disable the index:

```
ALTER INDEX <indexname> ON <tablename> DISABLE;
```

2/ Change datatype of the column

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> varchar(10) NOT NULL;
```

3/ Rebuild index (there is no ALTER INDEX... ENABLE):

```
ALTER INDEX <indexname> ON <tablename> REBUILD;
```